# Deedle, F# and issues with Frame.map

Tags: f#, deedle

I have an issue understanding the signatures of **Frame.map** (and eventually others too) when I could figure out easily **Series.map**.

**Here a quick example:**

```
let ts1 = 
  series
   [ ("A", "A1", "p1") => 0.5 
     ("A", "A1", "p2") => 2.
     ("A", "A2", "p3") => 2. 
     ("A", "A2", "p4") => 0.5 ]

let ts2 = 
  series
   [ ("A", "A1", "p1") => "A"
     ("A", "A1", "p2") => "B"
     ("A", "A2", "p3") => "C"
     ("A", "A2", "p4") => "D" ]

let F = ["ts1" =?> ts1 ; "ts2" =?> ts2] |> Frame.ofColumns
```

Let's say that I want to apply a function on the Series ts1, **there no issue:**

```
ts1 |> Series.map (fun _ v -> v * 2.)
```

Works as expected...

But if I want to use, let's say for the example:

```
let fun1 (a: float) (b: string) =
    match b with
    |"B" -> a ** 2.
    |"C" -> a ** 3.
    |_   -> 0.
```

On the Frame **F**, I just cannoy figure it out. I have tried calling columns.

I would not mind some help, as I cannot figure it out with previous posts/Deedle doc/etc... I am just stucked at the signature...

```
let F2 = F |> Frame.mapRows (fun k a -> (fun1 a.GetAs<float>("ts1") a.GetAs<string>("ts2")))
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of operation is very intuitive in MATLAB/R/Python using vectorized indexing.

In Deedle, `Frame.mapRows` will get every row as an `ObjectSeries`. My ugly solution would be like this

```
F
|> Frame.mapRows(fun _ v -> 
  match string v.["ts2"] with
  | "B" -> v |> Series.map(fun k v -> if k = "ts1" then box((unbox v) * 2.) else v)
  | "C" -> v |> Series.map(fun k v -> if k = "ts1" then box((unbox v) * 3.) else v)
  | _ -> v |> Series.map(fun k v -> if k = "ts1" then box(0.) else v)
)
|> Frame.ofRows
```

Comment: thanks zyzhu but I am indeed curious if there is something nicer

Comment: Just for information, what I do not like with this solution is the fact that I woukld like to use more complex functions and/or pass it in parameter.